# web service, internal proxy instead of external redirect or internal rewrite

Tags: java, web-services, spring

This is an external redirect:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(@PathVariable final long id, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final String relativeUrl = computeRelativeUrl(id); 
    System.out.println("DEBUG. relativeUrl: " + relativeUrl);

    response.sendRedirect(relativeUrl);
}
```

The problem with that is that the client needs to make two http requests to get the file.

This is an internal rewrite:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getFile(@PathVariable final long id, final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    final String relativeUrl = computeRelativeUrl(id);
    System.out.println("DEBUG. relativeUrl: " + relativeUrl);

    ServletContext context = RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(request).getServletContext();
    RequestDispatcher rd = context.getRequestDispatcher(relativeUrl);
    rd.forward(request, response);
}
```

The problem with that is the servlet which responds to the computed relativeUrl is not in the same servletContext.
That is, that servlet is deployed in the same webserver, but with two different jars/WEB-INFs.
So, the requestDispatcher cannot forward the request.

So, the question is, how can I make it work, without asking the client to make two http requests, and without making special configurations in the webserver.
also, `computeRelativeUrl(id)` has some logic which cannot be easily extracted 
(it is definitively not a solution to write a simple proxy configuration on the web server)

Any idea?

One possible solution is that my webservice makes a http request to the relativeUrl and returns this to the client (just like a proxy). It should return the content as well as all the http headers.

How can I easily achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to achieve, you can try to do a "cross context" dispatch.

```
ServletContext contextOfOtherWebapp = servletContext.getContext("/pathOfOtherWebapp");
```

Check the docs for [`ServletContext.getContext(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getContext%28java.lang.String%29)

It does however require the servlet container to allow this. If it doesn't by default, it might be a configuration setting to enable it.

Comment: unfortunately, crossContext is disabled by default http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

and I am not allowed to change this parameter :(
one possibility would be the proxy solution. any idea?

Comment: Well, I guess you could have your "proxy servlet" act as a regular client to the other servlet, using Apache HttpClient or similar.

Comment: i also guess so :) but the question is whether someone has already done it (and maybe it is already coded somewhere in javax.servlet), in a way that returns the content and all http headers of the proxified request.

Comment: Usually I set up Apache or nginx to do stuff like that. But I know there exists several "proxy servlets". For instance like this one: https://github.com/dsmiley/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet

Comment: but again, the proxified request is not know in advance. it is computed by the function computeRelativeUrl(id). so the request needs to be done inside my getFile web service. (it is definitively not a solution to write a simple proxy configuration on the web server)

Comment: Aha. I completely missed the dynamic part (sorry about that...). In that case, your own proxy client would be your best (and probably only) shot. Most proxy servlets I've seen use some sort of http client, so it should be ok, but maybe not as "easily" as you prefer :)